# Pronunciation of words ending in "-ds"

Tags: pronunciation, consonant-clusters

I'm wondering how to pronounce these kind of words:

> - wor**ds**
> - bir**ds**

I've tried to pronounce both /d/ and /z/ sound but it's really hard for me.

I noticed some of samples in dictionaries and it seems like they almost omit the /d/ sound.

Comment: without the /d/ sound you have *whirs* and *burrs*

Answer (score 7):

The plural suffix *-(e)s* is typically pronounced in one of three ways:

- /ɪz/ after sibilants (the six sounds /s/, /z/, /ʃ/, /ʒ/, /tʃ/, and /dʒ/).
- /z/ after voiced sounds (including vowels) other than sibilants.
- /s/ after voiceless sounds other than sibilants.

The /d/ sound is a voiced sound, and it's not a sibilant.  So, following /d/ the plural suffix is pronounced /z/.  *Birds* and *words* are pronounced /bɜrdz/ and /wɜrdz/ respectively.

Some words change form before the plural suffix.  For example, *leaf* /liːf/ becomes *leaves* /liːvz/ rather than **leafs* /liːfs/.  In these cases, the pronunciation of the plural suffix is based on the changed form, not the basic form.

Comment: +1 But it should be acknowledged that in real-life articulation the voicing on the /z/ is only fully realized before a voiced sound, such as a consonant, and is usually  attenuated before a voiceless consonant or a silence. The speakers of isolated dictionary examples must choose between exaggerating the /z/, which sounds unnatural, like old-fashioned 'elocutionists', or letting the /z/ trail off naturally to /s/ on its way to silence.

Answer (score 1):

In English, if a voiced consonant occurs at the end of a syllable,

1. Any other consonant in the same cluster is voiced (hence, /ridz/)
2. The preceding vowel gets lengthened. To many listeners, the length distinction is more important than the voicing distinction. So my practical advice, if you find /dz/ hard, is to exaggerate the vowel length when you communicate: /riiids/ will usually be heard as /ridz/.