# The phonetic transcription of the word 'copies'

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, phonetics, ipa

I checked more dictionaries and the phonetic transcription (IPA) for the word: 'copy' is [ˈkɑp i]. It's two syllables with stress on the first syllable.

I know that the plural of "copy" is "copies" and we add that -es suffix. As far as I know the -es suffix phonetically looks like [ɪz]. However, this doesn't make sense to me:

copy [ˈkɒp i]

copies [ˈkɒp i ɪz]

There is a long "i" vowel in the singular and the ɪ in ɪz is a short vowel.
Can someone explain me what is the phonetic transcription of the word "copies" more exactly?

Comment: If the singular word already ends with an [i] sound, the plural is usually pronounced [iz] and not [ɪz]

Comment: Thank you, Sander. Your time is greatly appreciated. Is it a two syllable word. Right? regardless if it's singular or plural.

Comment: It's always 2 syllables, yes.

Comment: General rules: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/18381/pronunciation-of-words-ending-in-ds/18382#18382

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short I in the "es" suffix gets assimilated (or merged) with /i/ (i.e. the ee vowel) if it precedes it.

e.g. *plac**es*** /ˈpleɪsɪz/ vs. *trophies* /troʊf**iz**/.